# Why the Delete icon button is not attaching the <select> in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-append

I've following HTML mark-up of a `<table>`

```
<table id="blacklistgrid_1"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="apnd-test">
    <tr id="reb1_1">
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select name="product_id_1[1]" id="product_id_1_1" class="form-control prod_list">
            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
            <option value="5" >Chesse</option>
            <option value="8" >Laptop an</option>
            <option value="9" >Prosecco</option>
            <option value="10" >Coffee</option>
            <option value="11" >Tea</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="pack[1]" id="pack_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity[1]" id="quantity_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="volume[1]" id="volume_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select name="units[1]" id="units_1" class="form-control">
            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
            <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
            <option value="7" >oz</option>
            <option value="9" >ml</option>
            <option value="10" >L</option>
            <option value="12" >gms</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="amount[1]" id="amount_1" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr id="reb1_2">
      <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="products" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>
      <td colspan="5"></td>                            
    </tr>
  </tfoot>                                           
</table>
```

I'm appending the  control on click of Add button. It's working fine. I'm also attaching the Delete icon to the newly added  but it's not getting assigned/displyed. Also when user clicks on any delete icon concerned `<select>` shoud get delete. I've written following code but it's not working.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).delegate('.products', 'click', function (e) {
        var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        var no = table_id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var first_row = $('#' + table_id).find('tbody tr:first').attr('id');
        var toBeCloned = $('#' + first_row).find('td:first').find('select:last');
        var new_row = toBeCloned.clone();
        var idCounter = toBeCloned.attr('id').split('_');
        var new_id = 'product_id_' + no + '_' + (parseInt(idCounter[3]) + 1);
        var new_name = 'product_id_' + no + '[' + (parseInt(idCounter[3]) + 1 + ']');
        var elementToAppendTo = $('#' + table_id).find('tbody tr:first .btn-group:first');
        $(new_row).appendTo(elementToAppendTo).attr('id', new_id);
        $(new_row).appendTo(elementToAppendTo).attr('name', new_name);
        $('<button id="' + sel_id + '" style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;margin-top: 6px;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>').appendTo(elementToAppendTo);
        //function to delete HTML select element from add rebate by product grid 
        //$('.delete').on('click', deleteRow);
        $('.delete').on('click', function () {
            var prd_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).remove();
            $("#" + prd_id).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Can some one please help me in this regard? For your reference here is jsFiddle link I've created with above HTML and jQuery code:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcn9e/3/)

Comment: sel_id is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you have used button `id=sel_id` and `sel_id` is not defined anywhere.

You need to used `id=new_id` like below

```
$('<button  id="'+new_id
   +'"style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;margin-top: 6px;"'
   +' type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert"'
   +' aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>')
.appendTo($(elementToAppendTo));
```

please see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcn9e/9/)

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
$('<button id="' + sel_id + '" style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;....
```

your 'sel_id' is undefined